# Array spread merge array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I merge arrays of objects using spread syntax?

My data `array` can be any length, I need to combine them all into `mergedResults`

Any ideas?

```
   Promise.all(apiPromises).then(data => {
                let mergedResults = []
                data.forEach(function(element) {
                    const { events } = element;

                    mergedResults[...events]

                    console.log(mergedResults)
                });
   });
```

Comment: You're trying to merge together every object in the array in to one resulting object? Can you give an example input and desired output maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add to an *existing* array with spread inside `[]`, you can only create a *new* array (like `concat` does):

```
mergedResults = [...mergedResults, ...events];
```

...which isn't very efficient if modifying the existing array is acceptable (but is common in situations where leaving the original array alone is important, such as when programming with immutable objects).

For that reason, you might use `push` with spread syntax instead:

```
mergedResults.push(...events);
```

---

Side note: You can use destructuring in the `forEach` parameter list rather than as a separate statement:

```
Promise.all(apiPromises).then(data => {
    let mergedResults = [];
    data.forEach(({events}) => {
    // -----------^^^^^^^^
        mergedResults.push(...events);
    });
    // ...presumably do something with `mergedResults` here...
});
```

Perhaps even throw in `for-of`:

```
Promise.all(apiPromises).then(data => {
    let mergedResults = [];
    for ({events} of data) {
        mergedResults.push(...events);
    }
    // ...presumably do something with `mergedResults` here...
});
```

Or as with all array operations where you visit all elements, you can shoehorn this into `reduce`, but you don't gain anything by it, it just makes things more complicated:

```
Promise.all(apiPromises).then(data => {
    let mergedResults = data.reduce((results, {events}) => {
        results.push(...events);
        return results;
    }, []);
    // ...presumably do something with `mergedResults` here...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to push them:

```
  mergedResults.push(...events);
```

If you do:

```
  mergedResults[ something ]
```

thats just a property access.

Comment: So that's what the W stands for. :-)

Comment: @crowder yeah when I joined SO I still cared somewhat about my privacy, but I gave up now ... :) (you still have to google a lot to find anything meaningful about me so ...)